# Any possible reasons why await axios.post(<valid request>) stalls for nearly a minute but only on Linux?

Tags: linux, typescript, electron, axios

I am attempting to perform a token request to my identity server by posting the details to my existing service. Upon reaching the `post` the service stalls for anywhere up to a minute (longest recorded was 58 seconds).

I have tried testing on both native hardware (Mint Cinnamon 19.1) and Virtual Machine (Ubuntu 18.04) with the same result. This problem does not occur on Windows or Mac.

Thinking it may have been some of the wrapped functions slowing things down, I have separated them out with some log lines. All lines up to and including

> Submitting payload via POST

are printed almost instantly.

```
console.log('Sending token request ');
console.log('Fetching string map');
const stringMap = request.toStringMap();
console.log('Beginning stringification');
const payload = this.utils.stringify(stringMap);

console.log('Submitting payload via POST');
const response = await axios.post(
  configuration.tokenEndpoint,
  payload,
  {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    responseType: 'json'
  });
console.log('Resolving \'performTokenRequest\'');
```

On Windows and Mac this request is sent and resolved within 300ms which is expected. However, on Linux (tested on Mint 19.1 native and Ubuntu 18.04 VM), this request stalls (not sent to the service, checked via debug attachment on the server side) for up to one minute. The timing seems arbitrary, sometimes it's very long, sometimes only ten or so seconds.

Once the message is sent the auth service it is processed and responds within 100ms or so, and the rest of the code continues processing in a speedy manner.

I cannot figure out why this would only occur on Linux and not anything else. I have tried searching the issues list for axios but I can't see anything. I was wondering if it were an OS setup problem, or something I can configure within axios that I've forgotten.

Comment: Further to this, I decided to run a production build and publish. At first, I thought the error still existed, but I was always running it from a terminal. Double clicking the electron AppImage output works as expected. It appears that the delay only occurs when the Electron process is associated with a terminal window. If it makes any difference, I'm using Terminator on Mint and xterm on Ubuntu.